# cocos2d. Tileset image file to sprite list?

Tags: dictionary, cocos2d-iphone, tiles, tile

I have a tileset. For example it is represented with this file:

[link](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/091/4/2/RPG_Maker_VX_RTP_Tileset_by_telles0808.png)

And I want to add to my game a level editor which has a panel with tile picker. How to split this image to sprite list to use inside this picker?

The problem is when you use cocos2d you use both tiled map and its tileset, but not separate tilesets.

Comment: Actually you can use separate tile set, but you can not use two tile set in one tmx layer. For that you have to create multiple layers.

Comment: I want to make my editor to generate the similar result as tiled editor. I don't need these maps in my editor, I need to use one tileset simultaneously only.

Comment: you don't need a sprite list, you can use cctextureatlas if all tiles are the same size

Comment: can you give some concrete examples?